# How would I prevent my robot from touching a certain line?

Tags: java, robocode

I'm quite new to java and robocode, so please bear with me if my questions are dumb.

I can calculate a line in which the opponent's bullet will travel, but I was wondering how I would go about storing and moving the robot so it doesn't touch any of these lines (I have to use a normal Robot, not an AdvancedRobot). Is there a method for something like this (I'm not looking for code, nor have I implemented this, I am just asking for suggestions on how to go about this)?

Comment: Please provide at least *some* example code.

Comment: In other words, you're asking why the code you've not shown us not working as expected. This is a very difficult type of question to answer, and you might want to make it easier by posting your [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)code with your question.

Comment: Can you use a WellGoodRobot? I believe they have this functionality built in.

Comment: Read up on [Wave Surfing](http://robowiki.net/wiki/Wave_Surfing). All of the top 50 robots in [roborumble](https://literumble.appspot.com/Rankings?game=roborumble) use it in some form. Understand the concept of [waves](http://robowiki.net/wiki/Wave), and follow the [Wave Surfing Tutorial](http://robowiki.net/wiki/Wave_Surfing_Tutorial).